# Select another item then searched Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

So basically what I need help in is:

I want to search for BBXXCODE with selenium-3.141.0, and Python 3.8.5.
I'm using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'BBXXCODE')]"` which is working as expected. But I need to somehow extract the id of the `<tr>` tag on top, because I want to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tr9"]/td[2]/h1').click()` to click on the `I need to select this` text.

Is there a way to do this or should I stay searching via the `I need to select this` text instead of the code?

This is the code piece:

```
<tr id='tr9'>
    <td></td>
    <td role='gridcell'>
        <span class='link'>I need to select this</span>
    </td>
    <td role='gridcell'>
        BBXXCODE
    </td>
</tr>
```

I hope it is mostly clear, if not, feel free to tell me I'll try to add more details to it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than get the ID and then find the other element (in two steps), I would suggest, if possible, that you just get it in one step. You can use the XPath below to find the desired SPAN based on the location of the BBXXCODE.

```
//tr[./td[contains(text(),'BBXXCODE')]]/td/span
```

Comment: For my specific case this is the fastes and easiest to do. I can use it with the click function and get the result within one step.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the id of the `<tr>` tag with respect to the text **BBXXCODE** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath* and *`parent`*:

  ```
  tr_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'BBXXCODE')]//parent::tr[1]").get_attribute("id")
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`ancestor`*:

  ```
  tr_id = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(., 'BBXXCODE')]//ancestor::tr[1]").get_attribute("id")
  ```

Comment: This is working perfectly, but as JeffC mentioned that answer is one step, no need anything else, than a .click().